# Salesforce lightning tab URL param is getting removed

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I had created a lightning component tab.
The tab was being called from a detail page button like this

/lightning/n/Forecast_Report_Account?accountId={!Account.Id}

All was working fine .
The URL looked like this before
https://xyz--bwdev2.lightning.force.com/lightning/n/Forecast_Report_Account?accountId=0011t00000DcQkF

But suddenly it has stopped working
As soon as I click on the button now - the lightning tab is opened but the url does not contain the param anymore.
I need the param to set to an attribute
The url now looks like this
https://xyz--bwdev2.lightning.force.com/lightning/n/Forecast_Report_Account

I was fetching the param like this
component.get("v.pageReference").state.accountId
But now its giving me empty string .

I have tried using implementing lightning:isUrlAddressable in the component still the same issue.

Has there been any recent update which is causing this ?
Is there any solution ?

Comment: can you update your question with the minimal required code too?